# How could humans wage a war with Olympus?

Tags: warfare, religion, gods

So if all the mythical things, creatures, and gods in the roman Olympus myths spawned on mount Olympus in our world and the military decided to wage a war against the gods how would they do that?

Comment: For Zeus, destroy the sky and air. For Poseidon destroy all the seas, for Hades overcome death - ie make humans immortal. The list goes on. This seems very broad to me as there are so many of them.

Comment: Are the gods going to be located on the Mount Olympus in Greece, or "Olympus" is a place located in another dimension which humans can't reach with their present technology?

Comment: "How could humans wage a war with Olympus".. badly. very, very badly.

Comment: How powerful are your Greek gods? The power of the Greco-Roman gods varies hugely depending on the story. In the Aeneid they are weak enough to be hurt by some mortal dude with a spear. In the story of Typhon they are powerful enough to shake the entire world as they battle.

Comment: @Daron seconded. It's not clear what form Greek gods we're fighting, so we can't give an answer.

Comment: [*Olympus Has Fallen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Has_Fallen). (And this question asks the community to develop the plot of a story for the querent.) (Quick, was there ever a conflict between the mortals as a whole and the Olympian gods as a whole? What caused it? How was it solved? Do you know what was the root cause of the Trojan War? How come that Zeus put so much effort into organizing the splendiferous wedding of the goddess Thetis with the mortal man Peleus?)

Comment: @AlexP there is no need for the story and the questions u ask are the creation of a story. Basically, the question is - how do we wage a war as a technological civilization against gods of the level depicted in mythology. Nuke them of course.

Answer (score 4):

## Call Kratos

In recent greek mythology, [Kratos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kratos_(God_of_War)) is a citizen from Sparta who finds out that he is Hercules's mortal brother. Due to a SNAFU involving a dispute between Athens and Sparta and a misanswered prayer to Ares, Kratos ascends to hero status, then to demigod status. He finally kills Ares and becomes the new god of war.

Kratos is kinda antisocial and psychotic, though, so the other gods tried to off him. Joke was on them, Kratos killed every single one of them. Then he moved north and kicked the ass of the norse gods. I imagine the egyptian ones are next.

Anyway, Kratos is your guy. He knows how to slay gods.

---

Edit, I got this valid objection to my plan:

> (...) it's the Governments vs Olympus, not Greek (actually video game) myth vs Olympus.

Making K a civil servant solves half of that. If the deerless city of Malden, Massachusetts could name Timothy Dexter the official Informer of Deer, I don't see why they couldn't name Kratos of Sparta the official Slayer of Greek Deities.

As for Kratos being a videogame character, that makes him as real as greek gods, so there.

Comment: Oh, alright then, this justifies the question. Hadn't heard of him.

Comment: Kratos the video game character maybe. But in Greek mythology he's on the side of Olympus making fun of Prometheus and acts of cruelty. Besides, it's the Governments vs Olympus, not Greek (actually video game) myth vs Olympus.

Comment: @Trioxidane make K a civil servant, problem solved ;)

Comment: +5 points for "recent Greek mythology"

Answer (score 2):

United we stand United we fall. Technology And/or the occult  Might take care of the magical creatures but there is nothing the humans even Allied together can do about literal gods walking the Earth. If the are going to win this fight they need to get some gods on there side.

1. Turn the gods against each other. The Greeks gods were far from United  if zues invaded earth his brothers but be willing to protect earth just to spite him.
2. Look to other religions  are the Greek gods are a thing  There might be other gods out there willing to negotiate.  Perhaps a deal can be struck get them to ally against Zeus. Really doubt any of them want a world where the Greek gods alone are worship.